# How to Create Managed account and transfer money from Managed account?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I want to create Custom Accounts in stripe so that I can managed it by my own platform. i have created platform on stripe. I am using stripe.Net for this purpose. I have created several account using this code :

```
  var account = new StripeAccountCreateOptions
        {
            Email = customer.Email,
            Managed = true,
            Country = customer.Country.ToString(),
            BusinessName = customer.BussinessName,
            BusinessUrl = customer.BussinessUrl,
            LegalEntity = new StripeAccountLegalEntityOptions()
            {
                FirstName = "imran",
                LastName = "shahid",
                BirthDay = 20,
                BirthMonth = 3,
                BirthYear = 1993,
                Type = "individual",
                AddressCity = "new york",
                AddressPostalCode = "12345",
                AddressLine1 = "kalma chok",
                AddressState = "new york",
                SSNLast4 = "5467",
                PersonalIdNumber = "127.0.0.1"
            },
            TosAcceptanceDate = DateTime.Today,
            TosAcceptanceIp = "127.0.0.1",

            ExternalCardAccount = new StripeAccountCardOptions()
            {
                AddressCity = "abc",
                AddressCountry = "US",
                Currency = "usd",
                Number = "4000056655665556",
                ExpirationYear = "2020",
                ExpirationMonth = "03",
                Cvc = "123"
            },
        };

        var accountService = new StripeAccountService();
        StripeAccount response = accountService.Create(account);
```

but when i visited website all accounts are unverified.

and for payments i am using this code

```
 var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = 1000,
            Currency = "usd",
            Description = "Charge it like it's hot",
            SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId = "*SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId*",
            ApplicationFee = 25,
            Capture = true
        };

        var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
        StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
```

How to get SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId? actually I want to deduct money from one customer and transfer it to my account and then I also want to transfer money from my account to customers account. I am not getting proper tutorial or any sample code for this purpose. can you help me out? I just want to do 3 things

1) creating verified managed account

2) charge customer(custom account)

3) transfer money to Customer(custom account)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your main problem is likely that you haven't uploaded a a verification document (and the associated png/jpeg of some form of photo-id)

I'm struggling with this myself.

The best way to tell what you need is to go on one of the unverified accounts in the Dashboard, it'll have a yellow alert box saying payments are disabled or somesuch. hit Edit and it'll give you a list of information it currently needs.

Most of it is in the Legal_Entity category which you've already done.

Good luck, let me know how it goes!

Comment: After creating managed accounts if we need to payments then should we have to take details of credit card every time or we can save it in our system or in stripe?

Comment: You can store the credit card details as a Card data object attached to a Customer  on your account.

You can also create External Accounts, which store bank account or card data for use in receiving payments.

Answer (score 0):

The Source Token is a token constructed from the card you want to use for the payment. you generate that separately as a one-time token, then feed the ID of it into the Charge.

Alternately you can use a specific existing Source, which is the ID of the card/bank account Source you want to use.

As with many things in Stripe, there are multiple approaches which are useful in different scenarios.